# Removing javascript key/value pairs by index

Tags: javascript, string, function, object, key

```
function removeString(obj) {
  var propertyArray = Object.values(obj);            //make array of just properties 
  for(var i = 0; i < propertyArray.length; i++) {
     if (typeof propertyArray[i] === "string")          //find string
     delete Object.keys(obj)[i];  //delete the key with the same index as the string
  }                                
  return obj;//return new object without string 
}

var testObject = {size: 6, name: 'String', age: 20}

console.log(removeString(testObject)) //I want {size: 6, age: 20}
```

I want above function delete field with value `string` instead what gets returned is the original object.

To anyone reading this/willing to help, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You need to do:

```
delete obj[Object.keys(obj)[i]]
```

Other than `delete Object.keys(obj)[i]`. Right now you are simply deleting a retrieved value `name` rather than the property `name` of the `obj` being `obj["name"]`. That's why it was never removed from `obj`. Here is a snippet example:

```js
function removeString(obj) {

var propertyArray = Object.values(obj);            
for(var i = 0; i < propertyArray.length; i++)      
if (typeof propertyArray[i] === "string")   
  delete obj[Object.keys(obj)[i]]                                 
return obj;                                                                                       
}



var testObject = {size: 6, name: 'String', age: 20}

console.log(removeString(testObject))
```

Comment: It uses a lot of unecessary ressources. (Get an array of keys for each iteration, that could be expensive).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I'm simply using the same code that the OP gave, that way it's clear why their code didn't work and show how to fix it. Yes there are better ways to do this, but I think this will show them the most clearly what was wrong with their initial code.

Comment: Thank you.  I know this isn't the best way to accomplish the desired output.  I knew I was close, but couldn't figure out what was going wrong.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You kind of have the right idea. The one problem is that you're trying to delete the key by index. Objects don't have an index associated with them, they are unordered. This means, unlike lists, you can't say `object[index]`, instead you're saying `object[key]`.

What you want to do is loop through each **key**, not value. Then you can look up that value and do your comparison, and then call `delete` using the key.

```
function removeString(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);

    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (typeof obj[keys[i]] === "string") {
            delete obj[keys[i]];
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I really like the alternative you provided as well as the explanation to go along with it.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys(obj)` will return an array of all the keys of `obj` (go through the keys of the object and copy them (just the keys not the values) into the result array and return it). So when you `delete` the `i-th` entry of that array, `obj` remains unaffected. To explain more `delete Object.keys(obj)[i]` is the same as:

```
var aCopyOfTheKeys = Object.keys(obj); // get a copy of all the keys of obj
delete aCopyOfTheKeys[i]; // remove the i-th property of aCopyOfKeys
```

So instead of removing an entry of an array that has nothing to do with `obj`, you'll have to `delete` the properties of `obj` directly using `obj[key]` like this:

```js
function removeString(obj) {
    // loop through the keys of the object obj
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        // if the value of this key is of type string
        if (typeof obj[key] === "string")
            // delete it
            delete obj[key];
    });
    return obj;
}

var testObject = {size: 6, name: 'String', age: 20}

console.log(removeString(testObject))
```

Comment: While this is a good alternative, it doesn't explain the OP's issue.